# INDEX & MATCH instead VLOOKUP

Tags: indexing, excel-formula, match

I have 2 validation lists, both have numbers & texts amongst them (but none of the lists have alpha-numeric symbols).  They are on another sheet called "Source".

I'm using the statement of:

```
=INDEX(Sources!$A$3:$A$32,MATCH(LEFT(Sources!$A$3:$A$32,3)&"*",Sources!$B$3:$B$42,0)).
```

But I keep getting #N/A. Can anyone help?

Comment: Is the sheet called "Source"? The formula references a sheet named "Sources"

Comment: Can you share your data or demo model of it to give us a better understanding of your problem

Comment: You're right Tah...   Is it called "Sources"

Comment: You're right Tah...   Is it called "Sources";   Here's the data...  Bikash...

010.10 - East
040.86 - East
057.68 - East
069.77 - East
083.10 - East
104.86 - East
109.07 - East
113.92 - East
120.21 - East
126.20 - East
130.50 - East
131.50 - East
135.41 - East
510.10 - West
540.86 - West
557.68 - West
569.77 - West
583.10 - West
604.86 - West
609.07 - West
613.92 - West
620.21 - West
626.20 - West
630.50 - West
631.50 - West
635.41 - West

Comment: forgive the formatting...

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to lookup a range within another range using `MATCH` formula. In your formula you are using match to lookup A3:A32 within B3:B42. Ideally the match formula can lookup only 1 value in B3:B42 and not the complete range of values.

Your formula should be,

```
=INDEX(Sources!$A$3:$A$32,MATCH(LEFT(Sources!$A$3,3)&"*",Sources!$B$3:$B$42,0))
```

If you want to drag formula varying the A3 to A32 , use the below,

```
=INDEX(Sources!$A$3:$A$32,MATCH(LEFT(Sources!A3,3)&"*",Sources!$B$3:$B$42,0))
```

This type of lookup with range within a range works only on `array formulas`. Your formula seems much of array formula. After pasting the formula in formula bar, press `ctrl + shift + enter` . This will make your formula as an array formula. If you do not want to use that as an array formula, try my formulas with just `enter`

Comment: Can you share your data or demo model of it to give us a better understanding of your problem – Bikash Behera Apr 14 at 8:56 
 

       
 
You're right Tah... Is it called "Sources" – user3224930 2 hours ago     
 

       
 
You're right Tah... Is it called "Sources"; Here's the data... Bikash... Data Up above...

Comment: @user3224930  did you try my answer?